# create() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Whenever I create a record I got an error:

> "create() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)"

in the given code:

```py
@api.model
@api.constrains('xyz')
def create(self,values,**kwargs):
    res = super(Project, self).create(values)
         return res
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `@api.constrains` in ORM create method. Create your own method with that decorator instead and it will be automatically called each time create method is executed or write method modifies `xyz`.

Comment: By the way what do you want to do with `@api.constrains('xyz')`?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```py
@api.model
@api.constrains('xyz')
def create(self,values):
     res = super(Project, self).create(values)
     return res
```

NOTE: You trying to pass one argument to `create` function, but actually the `create` function takes two arguments as per definition.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this is code:

```
@api.model
@api.constrains('xyz')
def create(self, vals):
    project = super(Project, self).create(vals)
    return project
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override `create` method you can see the following example:

class ClassName(models.Model):
    _inherit = "model.name" # Model to inherit from

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    record = super(ClassName, self).create(vals)
    # your code here        
    return record
```

Make sure you use the class name in the super method.

If you want to add constraints on `xyz` proceed as following:

```py
from openerp.exceptions import ValidationError

@api.constrains('xyz')
def _check_xyz(self):
    for record in self:
        # Check here the value of "record.xyz"
        # Then raise for example a validation error if it is evaluated to False
        # example: raise ValidationError("xyz must be ")
```

> > @constrains only supports simple field names, dotted names (fields of relational fields e.g. partner_id.customer) are not supported and will be ignored
> >     @constrains will be triggered only if the declared fields in the decorated method are included in the create or write call. It implies that fields not present in a view will not trigger a call during a record creation. A override of create is necessary to make sure a constraint will always be triggered (e.g. to test the absence of value).

Answer (score 0):

You cant use constrains and model decorators at the same time.